# How can i find center coordinates of a group object opencv

Tags: image, numpy, opencv, line, center

I want to center x,y coordinates of all delight lokums in this picture;
[marshmallows on a tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z3YO.jpg)

i tried a lot of things but i cant complete rectangles. 
[i get this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z3YO.jpg) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzTXZ.jpg)
target my project
[project target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDaG9.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread ('yl4.jpg')  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
#morphology
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)  
erosion = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
kernel = np.ones((17,17),np.uint8) 
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(gray , cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) 
#get binary
gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(opening, (21,21), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 1)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
#filter small dotted regions
nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh , None, None, None, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] #get CC_STAT_AREA component
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)
for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 275:   
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255
cv2.imshow('frame',img2)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.imwrite("outyl3.jpg", img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: As StackOverflow is not a code writing service, you should edit your code As a [mre] to attempt solving this problem into your question.

Comment: Include A representative input image, and an example of the output our code produced, with an explanation of what output you wanted.

Comment: There aren’t any input/output images in your question.

Comment: Thanks barny, i added images